# Facebook Publish

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to publish a message on my facebook wall from my application. First time the publish is successful. However during the second and successive times I am getting "The operation couldn't be completed. (FacebookErrDomain:10000)". please help me on this.

P.S:  I am not using ARC, eventually no static variables. 
      Trying to implement the SSO feature of facebook.

I am calling three methods in the app,

```
-(void)signintoFacebook{
    if (![self.facebook isSessionValid]) {
        NSArray *permissions=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"read_stream",@"publish_stream", nil];
        [self.facebook authorize:permissions];
        NSLog(@"first permission");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"second");
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(signedIntoFacebook)]) {
            [self.delegate signedIntoFacebook];
        }
    }
}

-(void)postToFacebook{
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [params setObject:@"Good Morning..!!" forKey:@"message"];
       [self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];

}
```

works fine for the first post. During the second try my error message is caught in this method

```
-(void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"The request failed to load %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: why is your error coming? because your code is incorrect? How can we help? we need to see your code

Comment: please find my edited question.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you see how I implemented it: https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare/blob/dev/iOS/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare.m

Comment: Check with below question:


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495287/fbsessiondelegate-methods-not-fired/9517538#9517538

Comment: check with below question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495287/fbsessiondelegate-methods-not-fired/9517538#9517538

Comment: You can check with url given as below:


[Facebook Helper Class][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495287/fbsessiondelegate-methods-not-fired/9517538#9517538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this method you get more inforamtion

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Err details: %@", [error description]);
};
```

please check `Err details:`

I think you have error code 506 , this error is duplicate status message

if you send same message again to again then error is generate, if you want to send same message then you use one trik

you logout facebook and again login , send message then error not generate.

Comment: I am getting the below description

UserInfo=0x86c8380 {error=<CFBasicHash 0x86c8520 [0x1c81b48]>{type = mutable dict, count = 3,
entries =>
 2 : <CFString 0x86929a0 [0x1c81b48]>{contents = "type"} = <CFString 0x86615e0 [0x1c81b48]>{contents = "OAuthException"}
 3 : <CFString 0x86c6f80 [0x1c81b48]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x8694fd0 [0x1c81b48]>{contents = "(#506) Duplicate status message"}
 6 : <CFString 0x86c8450 [0x1c81b48]>{contents = "code"} = 506

Comment: Thanks for your response. can u please explain a little bit more and suggest me any link to check this error code and message to rectify.